# Expand documentation popup in flutter development in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, documentation

I am trying to learn Flutter to develop android Apps using the famous course by Angela Yu.

My question is sometimes, how can we expand on the documentation offered by the auto-suggest - like this - When I write Navigator.pop - how can I get the expanded popup on the left ?
Im asking this for android studio.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got this - it's ctrl(^) + J